# How can I connect two android devices to the same network over the internet?

Tags: wi-fi, networking

Many phone functions (local WiFi-only games, networking, etc.) are only possible/are made much easier by having the two devices connected to the same network.

I'd like to do this, if possible, between two Android devices. I imagine a VPN would do the job, but I'm not sure. How can I connect two (separated by distance) Android devices to the same network?